# Django how to update existing database rows using pandas df.to_sql

Tags: python, django, pandas, postgresql, django-models

My goal is every day to update my `database lines by uploading a file containing the 7 past days data`.

So, I have to read the file with pandas and load it into my `django database`. And most of time, the `dataframe` will have `lines already present in the database` and `brand news lines which are not in the database`.

I would like to insert the `dataframe into my database` by replacing:

- the already  `existing lines` by the  `news lines` in the `dataframe`
- and also insert the `news lines` in the `dataframe` into the `database`.

**NB:** A line already exists if we have same `date`, same `advertiser`, and same `insertion_order` between the `database` and the `dataframe` we 're trying to upload.

After many research, I found this function, but I couldn't get it work in my case.

```
def upsert(table, con, keys, data_iter):
    
    data = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]
    insert_statement = insert(table.table).values(data)
    upsert_statement = insert_statement.on_conflict_do_update(
        constraint=f"{table.table.name}_pkey",
        set_={c.key: c for c in insert_statement.excluded},
    )

print(upsert_statement)
con.execute(upsert_statement)
```

And then, I call it in `df.to_sql`

```
df.to_sql(
  Xandr._meta.db_table,
  if_exists="append",
  index=False,
  dtype=dtype,
  chunksize=1000,
  con=engine,
  method=upsert
)
```

- the model

```
class Xandr(InsertionOrdersCommonFields):
    dsp = models.CharField("Xandr", max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Xandr"
        unique_together = [
            "date",
            "advertiser",
            "insertion_order"
        ]
        verbose_name_plural = "Xandr"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dsp
```

Comment: 1) From here [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html): *append: Insert new values to the existing table.*, so that is going to fail if you have existing PK's. 2) Postgres has [INSERT ... ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) that might work. You need to read the docs at the link for more information and then run a raw query. 3) The alternative is to load the data into a staging table and then use that to either INSERT or UPDATE records in the main table.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **Django ORM**. [`update_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) does exactly what you need.

Comment: is there any equivalent to df.to_sql in django ORM. I was using django with a for loop to create my instance  inside a list and then using bulk_create. But performance a very slow compared to df.to-sql. That's why I am using it.